# in the banner OR in to the banner OR on the banner OR to the banner?

Tags: prepositions

My sentence is:

> The text needs to be incorporated **in the banner**.

I asked is it "in the banner" or "on the banner" and this created a lot of different opinions:

> The text needs to be incorporated **in** the banner.
>   The text needs to be incorporated **in to** the banner.
>   The text needs to be incorporated **to** the banner.
>   The text needs to be incorporated **on** the banner.

How should that sentence be said so it's correct?

Comment: Your sentence is correct. Incorporate into can only be the next option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both "in" and "into" would be good choices. A clue to this usage is found in "**in** corporated".

"incorporated *to* the banner" does not look exactly right. No.

As far as "on", here is an example: "this text needs to be **on** the banner somewhere."  That sounds fine.

So, with the word "incorporated" included, then "into" or "in" are preferred. Without the word "incorporated", "on" is also valid.    In fact, even with "incorporated" there, "on" doesn't look entirely wrong...

You have many options here, there is not one scientifically correct answer.